# How do ensure static web site pages are fresh?

Tags: web

I have a static web site hosted on Amazon S3. I regularly update it. However I am finding out that many of the users accessing it are looking at a stale copy.

By the way, the site is: http://cosi165a-f2016.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com) and it's generated a ruby static site generator called nanoc (very nice by the way). It compiles the source material for the site: https://github.com/Coursegen/cosi165a-f2016 into the html, css, js and other files.

I assume that this has to do with the page freshness, and the fact that the browser is caching pages.

How do I ensure that my users see a fresh page?

Comment: By updating, are you refering to page content or static files (css, js)?

Comment: Yes, i change the content and then upload changed html primarily but potentially other files too.

Comment: Are your html files being cached as well?, regarding the javascript and css files you can read this article about cache-busting to prevent your files get cached http://curtistimson.co.uk/front-end-dev/what-is-cache-busting/

Comment: Have you tried using an 'expires' meta tag in your html?

Answer (score 1):

One common technique is to keep track of the last timestamp when you updated static assets to S3, then use that timestamp as a querystring parameter in your html.

Like this:

```
<script src="//assets.com/app.min.js?1474399850"></script>
```

The browser will still cache that result, but if the timestamp changes, the browser will have to get a new copy.

The technique is called "cachebusting".

There's a grunt module if you use grunt: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-cachebuster. It will calculate the hash of your asset's contents and use that as the filename.

Comment: That Sounds promising, but I don't understand it. The site (by the way: http://cosi165a-f2016.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com) is generated my a ruby static site generator called nanoc (very nice by the way). It compiles the source material for the site: https://github.com/Coursegen/cosi165a-f2016 into the html, css, js and other files. 

Where exactly would that script tag go and could it work in the scenario I describe above?

Comment: Joe, that's a great link. I will try it. By the way, I notice the example seems to focus on a css file. My interest is actually in all the html files too. You don't need to know nanoc to interpret this code: 

route '/styles/' do
  item.identifier.chop + fingerprint(item[:filename]) + '.' + item[:extension]
end

Do you think I need a similar line for all file types not just /styles/?

Comment: I don't know, sorry